# Joomla - Categories and sub-categories calendar

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I am new to joomla, and I was wondering if somebody could recommend me a plugin for a calendar that support events of a certain categories. Basically what I want to be able to do is the following:

I register several events of some category. For some events I register them as being of categories A and B. Now, in the calendar, I choose the filter category A. It gives me 10 results. Now, I want to apply another filter (category B) over this last set, in order to show me events of A and B.
This seems so trivial for me when not considering that I am doing this with JOOMLA, since I am using it for the first time. But with JOOMLA I have nooo idea how to start! Please help?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the more popular calendar extensions for Joomla is [JEvents](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/95/details).

You can find a demo if it [here](http://www.jevents.net/en/demo).